# Промежуточные пустые элементы в .contents BS4

Tags: python, requests, beautiful-soup

Допустим, я хочу получить некоторую информацию из блока, в котором так-же содержатся какие-то элементы.
Сначала я делаю запрос к этой странице, и, сразу использую BeautifulSoup для получения HTML кода:

```
req = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'lxml')
```

Затем,я выделяю интересный для меня блок:

```
data = soup.find_all('div', {'class':'_si_container'})
```

Далее, чтобы перемещаться по дереву вниз, я использую `.contents`, но, этот метод предоставляет дерево через один элемент, т.е в виде:

`data[0].contents[0]` содержит в себе переход на новую строку: `000:'\n'`

data[0].contents[1] же, уже содержит в себе некоторую информацию о дочернем блоке : `001:'div class=data ...'`

Вопрос: могу ли я пропустить элементы, которые содержат в себе переход на новую строку, как в `000:'\n'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Еще немного полистав документацию, понял, что элементы с `'\n'` имеют тип [NavigableString](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigablestring), и сделав списочное выражение следующего вида: `data2 = [x for x in data[0].contents if type(x) is not NavigableString]` я получил список `data2` содержащий только полные элементы.